# Design an algorithm to detect cycle in graph G

Tags: algorithm

What would the following algorithm look like:

a linear-time algorithm which, given an undirected graph G, and a particular edge e in it, determines whether G has a cycle containing e

I have following Idea:

for each v that belongs to V, 
if v is a descendant of e and (e,v) has not been traversed then check following:

if we visited e before v and left v before we left e then 
the graph contains cycle

Comment: As this appears to be homework, you may want to show what your thought on how to solve this would be.

Comment: I will give you a hint: your idea is already more complicated than is necessary.  Since it is an undirected graph, finding a cycle is simpler than you seem to think...

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Here is a hint of the way I would choose: (e,v) is a part of a cycle if and only if there are at least 2 disjoint simple paths between e and v.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your homework so I'll just give a little hint - use the properties of breadth-first search tree (with root in any of the two vertices of the edge e), its subtrees which are determined by neighbors of the root and the edges between those subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

Per comingstorm's hint, an undirected edge is itself a cycle. A<->B back and forth as many times as you like.

Comment: This is a trivial case. It's commonly held that a cycle in the context of an undirected graph always must include three or more vertices (CLRS and other books mention this convention).

Comment: And must not traverse the same edge more than once.